# Craft CMS logo still showing on CP Login page

Tags: control-panel

We have uploaded a logo in the CP, but the CP Login page still has the craftcms logo under the login box. Perhaps a config setting to remove this that I don't know about?

Comment: Do you happen to be using a load balanced server setup?

Answer (score 3):

As of Craft 2.5, by default you will see your Site Name in plain text above the login form, and a light Craft CMS logo below it. If you have Craft Client/Pro and upload a custom Login Page Logo from Settings → General, the plain text Site Name will get replaced with that logo, but the Craft CMS logo will remain.

The Login Page Logo was never meant to be used to white-label the CMS - even pre-2.5 if you uploaded a custom logo, there would still be Craft and P&T references in the CP footer (which hasn’t changed).

Comment: Didn't you advertise that a benefit of a Craft Pro license allows you to debrand it?

Comment: @user1463467 We file the features under "System Branding" on https://craftcms.com/pricing, and back in e Craft 1.x days they were part of the "Rebrand" package, but never have we suggested it's a true white-labeling solution. If we ever allowed that it would cost significantly more than $299.

Answer (score 1):

The logo is stored in `craft/storage/logo/` which is a in a path that's often in your `.gitignore`